# How to set disabled btn background color as enabled ? ( Bootstrap )

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such problem: I need to make disabled btn, and when user wants he clicks on some link and enable it.

BUT I can't make disabled btn look as normal btn. I mean - can't set normal background color.

Here is jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/KckU3/14/

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple hack

```
.report:disabled{
    opacity: 1;
    background: #91b958;
    color : white;
}​
```

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/KckU3/15/)

Comment: Is it possible to change font color in IE8 ? It grey constantly.

Comment: @MID i'm not sure since i'm using linux.